# Damaged 4x4 grid

Tags: mathematics, pattern, grid-deduction

John had a great party yesterday ; but he had a very important piece of paper in his pocket, and an *unidentified liquid* damaged it. One third of the information is lost. It looks like this now :

[image]

The yellow numbers are ranging from **2** to **9** (**every yellow number is different from all the others**). They are assigned to the row/column under them/on their right.

This grid is very important for John. Unfortunately he doesn't remember the pattern he used to create it *(John really can't hold his liquor)*.

Can you help him **find the 8 missing numbers** ?

John's memory will recover over time, and hints might pop after a few days.

*Good luck.*

Comment: "This is a 4x4 grid with every number from 2 to 9 assigned to a row/column." Is this right or am I missing something?

Comment: I edited the image, things about these yellow numbers should be clearer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If n is the handle (yellow number) for a given row or column then the sum of the numbers in that row/column should be equal to n*(n+1) +1

For example, in the third row, sum = 8*9+1 = 73

[image]

Comment: n*(n+1) +1 ... which is the $n$th triangular number $T_n$ plus one. Well spotted.

Comment: Exactly ! More precisely, the sum of the numbers is 111 base n (which is n^2+n+1).The hardest part was figuring out the 5, because you have to realize 21+31+43+73=7+13+57+91. Well done.

Comment: Thank you @classicalMpk! Really enjoyed solving this one. Yes, figuring out between 5 and 7 is the tricky part.